# Curses isn't registering mouse clicks in Python

Tags: python, mouse, ncurses, curses

I want to make naughts and crosses (or tic-tac-toe in some places) in Python. [Here](https://pastebin.com/ZBVEqNG6) is my code so far.

```
import curses
board = {"1A": " ", "2A": " ", "3A": " ", "1B": " ", "2B": " ", "3B": " ", 
"1C": " ", "2C": " ", "3C": " "}

s = curses.initscr()
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
curses.mousemask(1)
w.nodelay(False)


def printboard():
    w.addstr(sh // 2 - 2, sw // 2 - 4, "{} | {} | {}".format(board.get("1A"), board.get("2A"), board.get("3A")))
    w.hline(sh // 2 - 1, sw // 2 - 4, "-", 9)
    w.addstr(sh // 2, sw // 2 - 4, "{} | {} | {}".format(board.get("1B"), board.get("2B"), board.get("3B")))
    w.hline(sh // 2 + 1, sw // 2 - 4, "-", 9)
    w.addstr(sh // 2 + 2, sw // 2 - 4, "{} | {} | {}".format(board.get("1C"), board.get("2C"), board.get("3C")))



while True:
    printboard()
    w.addstr(sh // 2 + 4, 1, "Naught's turn. Click on where you would like to place your naught.")
    w.refresh()
    event = w.getch()
    if event == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
        _, mousex, mousey, _, _ = curses.getmouse()
        print(mousex, mousey)
        w.refresh()
```

I've read the docs, and the code looks correct. When I run it in the terminal, the board appears, and it prints the text. But when I left click, the program does nothing. I don't know what's wrong with it.

EDIT:

Found out why it wasn't working. I just added `curses.mousemask(curses.BUTTON1_CLICKED)` before `w.nodelay(False)` and `w.keypad(True)` after `w.nodelay(False)`.

Answer (score 0):

short: the program does not call [**`keypad`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.keypad)

long: 
Python curses uses ncurses to get the mouse events.  Refer to the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Predefined-key-codes) for `getch`, which says

> The following special keys are defined in **`<curses.h>`**.
>
> - Except  for  the special case **`KEY_RESIZE`**, it is necessary to enable
>            keypad for getch to return these codes.
>
> **`...`**
>
> - **`KEY_MOUSE`**  is returned for mouse-events (see [**`curs_mouse(3x)`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_mouse.3x.html)).  This
>            code relies upon whether or not [**`keypad(3x)`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad) has  been  enabled,  because  (e.g., with xterm mouse prototocol) ncurses must read escape
>            sequences, just like a function key.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I added `w.keypad(1)` right after `w.nodelay(False)`, but it doesn't do anything. I also tried `w.keypad(True)`.